# update table in short way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have states table and stores 56 states and IDs, and I am updating my  value column in FieldValue table based on those ID stored in [Cases] table. I can use case statement to get the result, I don't want to repeat case statement 56 times

```
Update cv 
set Value = 
        case when 
            c.[state] = 1 then 13
            c.[state] = 2 then 14
            c.[state] = 3 then 15
            .
            .
            .
        End     
from 
    [Cases]  c
join 
    [files] f on f.FileName  = c.Name 
join 
    Recordset CR on CR.RecordId = f.id and RecordId = 3
join 
    FieldValue cv on cv.RecordsetId = cr.Id and cv.FieldId = 6
where 
    c.[State] is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If state and the value to update have some kind of relationship (Like value = state + 12 as I see in your example) you could do

```
update cv
set value = c.[state] +12
from [Cases]  c
join [files] f on f.FileName  = c.Name 
join Recordset CR on CR.RecordId = f.id and RecordId = 3
join FieldValue cv on cv.RecordsetId = cr.Id and cv.FieldId = 6
where c.[State] is not null
```

If there is no relationship at all, you will need to either write 56 lines or a function that returns the expected value (Inside it will be 56 lines long), this is a better aproch in case new values will be needed in the future

```
update cv
set value = fn_value_from_state(c.[state])
from [Cases]  c
join [files] f on f.FileName  = c.Name 
join Recordset CR on CR.RecordId = f.id and RecordId = 3
join FieldValue cv on cv.RecordsetId = cr.Id and cv.FieldId = 6
where c.[State] is not null
```

Even in the first case the function is better if the value-state relationship changes